# PermitrootLogin no in sshd but sshd -T shows permitrootlogin yes

Tags: rhel7, sshd

so I've set up "PermitRootLogin no" in /etc/sshd_config and I have restarted the sshd service but the root user can still login via ssh.

Further investigation shows that the run-time config differs from the sshd_config file:

```
[root@CEBECOM-Hq5AT03 ~]# grep PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin no
[root@CEBECOM-Hq5AT03 ~]# service sshd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  sshd.service
[root@CEBECOM-Hq5AT03 ~]# sshd -T |grep -i permitrootlogin
permitrootlogin yes
```

I also tried to restart the machine but still I can login with root...

Any idea?

Edit: I have some more info.

I found out that I have to put the PermitRootLogin before a Match directive in order for it to work:

```
# here it works
PermitRootLogin no
Match Group sFTP
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/salsftp
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no

# here it doesn't work
# PermitRootlogin no
```

I can't find a reason why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok I got it. From the `sshd_config` man page:

> Match   Introduces    a conditional block.  If all of the criteria on the
>            Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the **following lines**
>            override those set in the global section of the config file,
>            **until either another Match   line or the end of the file**

So if I put the `PermitRootlogin` after the Match this will be considered as part of the Match configuration. Since root is not on the sFTP group then the `PermitRootLogin` directive was ignored.